# Make Eclipse auto-complete predict .add() instead of .addAll() when .add() has already been used once

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Normal Eclipse prediction:

[image: "Correct" (desired) Prediction]

Prediction after .add() has been used already:

[image: Weird prediction of .addAll()]

I'd like for the second case to still predict .add() as the first choice, instead of pushing it below the 3% chance addAll just because it's been marked as 'used'. Is there any way to make it do so? I'm not sure what the exact conditions are but it's really an annoying prediction considering how rarely I actually need to use addAll().

Edit: After further testing it seems to only suggest addAll() when add has been used in a different code block at the same "depth".